# Finding text of sibling element jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to get the text of sibling element that is defined by a certain class name. For example in the code below, I want to find out the value of fund_name when I press the button. This code is actually in a loop so there are many rows of fund_names followed by a button for each row:

```
for($k=0; $k < $count; $k++)
{
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   ?>
   <tr class="tbl_fund_list">
       <td class="fund_name"><?php echo($row['fund_name']); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo($row['inv_nav']); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo($row['date']);?></td>
       <td><?php echo($row['inv_nav']*$row['inv_qty']);?></td>
       <td><button class="terminate_btn">Go</button></td>
   </tr>
        <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get sibling of parent `<td>` of the button using `parent()` and `siblings()`

```
$('.terminate_btn').click(function(){
   var txt = $(this).parent().siblings('.fund_name').text();
   console.log(txt)    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to first select the common parent element using `closest`, and then `find`ing the sibling element.

```
$('.terminate_btn').click(function () { 
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.fund_name').text()) 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.